# How to Enable ToolTip for Custom Add-Ins in Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-addins

I am creating word add-ins using "Office.js" and there are a textbox and button. I try to add to Tooltip for that button but it doesn't visible.

I attached code here.

```
<table class="Editor-Workflow">
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Preview</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <textarea id="areaDiv" rows="5"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="addComment" style="background-color:transparent;border-color:black;" title="Review and Insert Comment"><img src="Images/comment_blue.png" alt="Add Comment" /></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image: This is output of image]

On tap of the image, I have to put a tooltip(Title) that is visible to the user. If anyone has an idea about that please let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Why don't you use MS Fluent UI?

Comment: @roa I am unable to understand. Can you please add a link or give me an example of that.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/